# Actionscript [Error #2036: Load Never Completed] with dynamic generated images

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, zend-framework, image

I'm working with an image caching system that generates different images based on a url route. The source images live outside the document root and cached versions are added to /cache in the webroot. Long story short, in Flash, if I point a `Loader` to the route, I get a "Load Never Completed" error the first time (if the cached image has yet to be generated).

```
Error opening URL 'http://characters.dev/cache/Pledges/16107/48_48c/jen001.jpg'
Error #2036: Load Never Completed. URL: http://characters.dev/cache/Pledges/16107/48_48c/jen001.jpg
```

The cached image is still generated and the next time I run the application the actual file loads without error. I've got the proper headers being sent when generating the initial image and writing it, so I'm wondering why flash isn't getting the response (seems to works fine in a browser window).

```
header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
echo $this->getResponse()->setBody(file_get_contents($cachedFile));
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? The errors seems to "bog down" the flash application.

---

If it helps, here's the response headers:

**Request to generate image:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2009 17:52:49 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6b746d4ed010c288a824522597698ea2; expires=Fri, 24-Jul-2009 17:52:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.characters.dev
Content-Length: 3575
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

**Request when image is cached:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2009 17:53:27 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Jun 2009 17:52:50 GMT
ETag: "24e6c62-df7-a8bd0080"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3575
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash IDE issue it seems. Not really fixable.

Comment: Sorry but... what does this "answer" mean? How can the IDE be causing an error in the player?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar issue, to stop the error appearing you want to catch the IOErrorEvent.IO_Error

```
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError_handler, false, 0, true);

public function ioError_handler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
   Alert.show(event.toString());
}
```

Whilst this got rid of the error, some of the images where not loading in Opera. In the end I got this to work by changing the image handler code (asp.net c#) to

```
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);
context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
context.Response.BinaryWrite(photo);
```

before when I tried to view the image in the browser the photo would load, but it wouldn't finish loading in Opera, hence not firing the load complete event.

Hope this helps, (even if it is in a different language)

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I have a listener for IO_ERRORs (the output I posted is the result of the Alert you show). And I am setting the headers the same way. Not sure. The errors don't seem to be thrown when the Flash object is in the browser, so perhaps it's just an IDE thing.